# Rendering audio graph with correct volume level

Tags: python, matplotlib, audio, waveform

On the images below, the same audio file is represented. On the left side, there's a **correct, original and NOT NORMALIZED audio preview**.

I want to fix the following problems of the matplotlib's graph:

- ### Correct the audio level (amplitude)
- Stop truncating the height

  - There's small space at Y-axis
  - **I've tested normalized files with different sample rates - this padding occurs regardless of audio level**

---

| Correct preview | Matplotlib |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

---

Code I've used:

```py
import numpy as np
import wave, sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File_Name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[1])
plt.rcParams["axes.xmargin"] = 0

#-=-=-=-#

try:
    Audio = wave.open(sys.argv[1], "r")
except Exception:
    raise SystemExit("WAV format not integer, exiting.")

if Audio.getnchannels() > 1:
    raise SystemExit("Not a mono file, exiting.")

Signal = Audio.readframes(-1)
Signal = np.fromstring(Signal, "int16")
Time = np.linspace(0, len(Signal) / Audio.getframerate(), num = len(Signal))

#-=-=-=-#

plt.plot(Time, Signal, color = "#000000")
#plt.axis("off")
#plt.savefig(os.path.splitext(File_Name)[0] + ".png",
#   bbox_inches = "tight", transparent = 1, pad_inches = 0
#)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The issue is not reproducible without the sample file., and **all** imports.

Comment: Try to set the aspect ratio (height / width.)...  `plt.gca().set_aspect(1/2.5)`... You can change the number...

Comment: You can to set the limits of the axis... Example: `plt.ylim(-1.5*30000, 1.5*30000)`